# How to calculate the forces that need to be applied on two points based on a single force applied somewhere else in 2D space

Tags: vectors

I have a object that is fastened at to points. The object has a uniform density. We know the center of mass of the object. Is there a way to calculate the forces that need to be applied to those two points to keep the object stationary if we have a force somewhere in 2D space?

[Here is a picture of the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC21n.jpg)

[to clarify the picture, the yellow points are the two fastening points, the cyan point is the center of mass, the red arrow is the force]

Comment: More detail required please. The centre of mass cannot be of the 2 points only. So there is supposedly an object such that the cyan point is the centre of mass of that object, and the two points are just some random points on that object?

Comment: yes, sorry that i didn't specify that earlier

Comment: Is the object a rigid body?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to talk about forces acting on "points" unless the point has a mass. But if we also assume the rigid body has uniform distribution of mass then your question might be answerable.

Comment: I'll let someone else take over from here because I'm not really sure. Too many unknowns.

Comment: The force acts on the center of mass as a torque that you can compute with the vector product r x F. It will try to rotate the body around the center of mass, but the restrictions work against it. The torque at the restrictions is the same (rigid body) just with different radius vector, so will e.g. be one third of the original force in opposite direction at the right (yellow) point.